# in operator in sql from asp.net c# for update multiple Record

Tags: c#, webforms

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLStatusChange" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem>-Select-</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Just Received</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Post Approval</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatusChange" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnStatuschange"
        runat="server" Text="Status Change" onclick="btnStatuschange_Click" />
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
protected void btnStatuschange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string str = @"Update TblMasterinfo SET AppLoanStatus=@AppLoanStatus Where appid in (@Statuschange)";
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Statuschange", Convert.ToInt32(txtStatusChange.Text));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppLoanStatus",DDLStatusChange.SelectedValue);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

I input into txtStatusChange these appid for update record: 17110,17147,17524,17736,15906,17268,16440,17241 mention that when I update single recored like 17110, that update successfully. error is occured when more than one recored are updated

**Exception Details:** `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: Can you please try                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Statuschange", Convert.ToString(txtStatusChange.Text));?

Comment: the problem is  when you try to update more than one record, try to split the record into a list.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a List from your input

```
var ids = (from x in String.Split(',', txtStatusChange.Text)
           select int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToList();

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Statuschange", ids);
```

**Update**: To avoid using a List parameter (which might not work for sql sever) you could use this approach:

```
var ids = (from x in String.Split(',', txtStatusChange.Text)
           select int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToList();    
var idString = String.Join(',', ids);

var str = String.Format(
    @"Update TblMasterinfo SET ... Where appid IN ({0})", idString);
```

Since you are casting your string into a List and creating a new String this is save from SQL injection so I woudn't mind not using a parameter here.

Comment: This is not posible, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work (with mysql I am pretty sure that it would work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use normal SQL parameters for IN clause but you can use table valued parameters. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause/337864#337864). but it is bit complex

You can create sql string without parameter as below. That will be easy way but **make sure that your input properly validated**

```
string input ="17110,17147,17524,17736,15906,17268,16440,17241";
string str = string.Format("Update TblMasterinfo SET AppLoanStatus=@AppLoanStatus Where appid in ({0})",input);
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Statuschange", Convert.ToInt32(txtStatusChange.Text));
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I just have update:   string str = @"Update TblMasterinfo SET AppLoanStatus=@AppLoanStatus Where appid in (" + txtStatusChange.Text + ")";

Comment: Thanks Everyone for support me.